# How to connect to a redis server via Unix domain socket using hedis in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, redis, connection-string, unix-socket

I'm looking for how to connect to a redis server via Unix domain socket using [hedis](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis), as advertised in the hackage page:

> **Connect via TCP or Unix Domain Socket:**
>   TCP sockets are the default way
>   to connect to a Redis server. For connections to a server on the same
>   machine, Unix domain sockets offer higher performance than the
>   standard TCP connection.

From the constructors of [`ConnectInfo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hedis/0.6.2/doc/html/Database-Redis.html#t:ConnectInfo), as well as the [`defaultConnectInfo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hedis/0.6.2/doc/html/Database-Redis.html#v:defaultConnectInfo), it seems that we should fill in the `connectPort`, since it has type `PortID` which has a constructor named `UnixSocket`. But it only shows `UnixSocket` is a `String`, without details of format, etc.

So how to fill in the `connectPort` to connect via Unix domain socket? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:** I tried it out and found it's not that hard. Below is my hello world.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Database.Redis

myConnectInfo :: ConnectInfo
myConnectInfo = defaultConnectInfo { connectPort = UnixSocket "/tmp/redis.sock" }

main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- connect myConnectInfo
    runRedis conn $ do
        set "hello" "hello"
        set "world" "world"
        hello <- get "hello"
        world <- get "world"
        liftIO $ print (hello,world)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a Haskell user at all, and I cannot test it, but I would say you just have to provide the path of the socket file in this string.

Instead of:

```
connectPort           = PortNumber 6379
```

you would have:

```
connectPort           = UnixSocket "/tmp/redis.sock"
```

Of course, /tmp/redis.sock should be declared in the server-side Redis configuration file using the following parameters:

```
# Specify the path for the unix socket that will be used to listen for
# incoming connections. There is no default, so Redis will not listen
# on a unix socket when not specified.
#
unixsocket /tmp/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 755
```

Please note by default, unix domain socket parameters are commented out.

Comment: Why do you use 755 as the socket permission here? Are there times where you would want the everyone to have exec and read permission on the socket?